# commerce/cart/updateCart throws page not found

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, craft3

Adding products to the cart throws a page not found (404) error that has this header;

```
Page not found.
↵
Caused by: Invalid Route – yii\base\InvalidRouteException
Unable to resolve the request: commerce/cart/updateCart
in /Users/a/Sites/ae-dev/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php at line 128
```

Very strange. Anyone encounter this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your tag, I assume you're using Commerce 2.

Controller [actions in Craft 3 use `kebab-case`](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#request-params), now, so your action should be `commerce/cart/update-cart`.

Comment: Thanks—now I'm not getting an error, but nothing gets added to the cart, and instead of the cart redirect I get sent to the homepage.

Comment: Somehow managed to sort it out with purchasable.purchasableId instead of purchasable.getId, but the redirect is still wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Ah, my bad—not as simple as copy-pasting from Commerce 1 (duh). Some aspects have changed, like kebab-case and {{ redirectInput('shop/cart') }}